# integration of $\log ((A\exp (-x^2)+B)$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to integrate the following equation to calculate the ergodic capacity.
But im now in trouble since the term inside log is varying.
my first eqaution was

$\mathbb{E}_\theta \left[ \log\left(1+\frac{P(\theta|\alpha_i+\Theta_i/2,\Theta_i^2)}{\sum_{j\neq i}^N P(\theta|\alpha_j+\Theta_j/2,\Theta_j^2)}\right)\right]$

where $P(\cdot|A,B)$ is a Gaussian pdf with mean $A$, and variance $B$.
After applying $\log(A/B)=\log A - \log B$, the problem becomes the following equation:
$$\int_a^b \log(A e^{-x^2}+B)\,dx$$

Here, I tried to substitute $A e^{-x^2} +B = t$ but i couldn't finish it. 
Is there any easy way to calculate it?
Thank you.

Comment: there is no condition on $A$ or $B$. but partial answer with some restrictive condition is also helpful.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, an antiderivative of the function $x \mapsto \log(e^{-x^2}+1)$ cannot be expressed in terms of mathematical functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT :

I don't think that a closed form exists. Is an infinite series of function erf convenient for you ?

[image]

Comment: Thank you. :)
can I assume that the term inside the summation will decrease as k increases?  I want to use big $O$ notation.. 
is it possible ?

Comment: Since $\text{erf} (b\sqrt{k})-\text{erf}(a\sqrt{k})$ tends to $\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}$ while $k$ tends to infinity, it seems that the general term decreases if $B>A$.

Comment: agreed.   It seems $\int \!\ln  \left( {{\rm e}^{-{x}^{2}}}+1 \right) \,{\rm d}x$ is not an elementary function.